# Class 'Dispatcher' and class ''Router'' not found

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

What I did:

I make a project in `CakePHP 2.2.3`. It worked fine till I did some changes in css.
What happened

When i refreshed the page in browser I get following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Dispatcher' not found on my site path/app/webroot/index.php on line 91

Fatal error: Class 'Router' not found
```

FYI I had already cleared all the cache.

Comment: Must have done more than change the css. I would start all over if it's still new.

Comment: I am sure about that i even tried to add manual path in app/webroot/index.php but still to effect.. I was working fine and i was about to finish it. Sudden change occur. I even checked the library file but still not able to find the error.. The problem is on line...
$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

Comment: @AnmolChanana Not really. The problem is that it isn't autoloaded somehow. Anyway, revert to the last commit, and everything should be fine, yes? :)

Comment: Thanks all, well I asked my senior and he gave me best solution. The problem was that something was not save  or file got corrupted as I was developing on ftp directly.It was not saved well. I JUST RELOADED "LIB" FOLDER FROM FRESH COPY. and everything works again.